# For a certain date interval in a pivot table, check for each row in a power pivot table if it overlaps

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a list of employees together with the dates that they started and the days that they quit:

```
Name    Started     Quit
Liza    2014-01-01  2014-07-18
Erik    2003-01-01  
John    2007-02-05  2015-02-12
Sigurd  2012-02-20  
Ivo     2014-01-01  2014-12-31
```

In a pivot table, for any filtered date interval I want to see the number of people that have been working at least one day in that interval.

So if I would choose `2014-12-31 - Any time` in the pivot table, I would get:

```
Erik    
John
Sigurd  
Ivo
```

How can I create this behavior using a Power Pivot data model?

Ideas for possible solution:

I imagine that I would create either some kind of calculated field for this or maybe a new junction table with the headers `Name`, `Month`, `Working (boolean)`. But I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with adding a measure that takes account of the blanks in your "quit" column:

```
[Lasteffectivedate]:=IF(ISBLANK(LASTDATE(Employees[Quit])),TODAY(),LASTDATE(Employees[Quit]))
```

Then you can add another measure that determines if the employee was active on the selected date or dates:

```
[IsActive]:=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Employees),FILTER('Employees',firstdate(Employees[Started])<=LASTDATE('Date Table'[Date])),FILTER('Employees',[Lasteffectivedate]>=FIRSTDATE('Date Table'[Date])))
```

This assumes that you have a disconnected date table which is used as the source for your date selection.

[image]

Comment: Is the first formula for a measure or for a calculated column or would it work as either?

Comment: This is a measure. You'd need to change it for a column.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt! It doesn't work however. I get the number of people who have started with [IsActive]. I don't know why but the people who have quit are not substracted.

Comment: @user1283776 Well, I've just recreated it copying your data from this Question and my measures from the Answer and it works perfectly. Are the "Quit" dates in your table being recognised by excel as dates?